# $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: [X^n]$ is invertible in $K[X]/(X^3+X^2+1)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory

Setting: Field $K$

I have to show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: [X^n]$ is invertible in
$K[X]/(X^3+X^2+1)$.

I have simply no idea.

Comment: As a side note, $K[X]/(X^3+X^2+1)$ is a field if and only if $X^3+X^2+1$ is irreducible over $K$ if and only if it has no root in $K$. Which is certainly not the case if $K=\mathbb{F}_3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: modulo $X^3+X^2+1$, we have
$$X(-X^2-X)=1,$$
which means the inverse of $X$ is $-X^2-X$. Hence all powers of $X$ are invertible modulo $X^2+X^2+1$.

Comment: Why X^3+X^2+1 is inversible is clear, but why all powers of X? Could you explain that? Thanks!

Comment: Take the same power of the  inverse of $X$. Anyway, in a commutative ring, if $ab$ is invertible, each of $a$, $b$ is invertible.

Comment: Consider a more general point of view: if $ab$ is invertible, there exists an element $u$ such that $u(ab)=1$. But this also means $(ub)a=1$ and $(ua)b=1$. Thus $a$ and $b$ are invertible.

Comment: This rule is totally known, but how does it help me here. What is my a, what is my b. and how does it help?

Comment: If $uX^n\equiv 1$, then $X(uX^{n-1}=1$, hence the inverse of $X$ is $uX^{n-1}$. Conversely, if $v$ is the inverse of $X$ mod. $X^3+X^2+1$, $v^n$ is the inverse of $X^n$.